# echo prints just one string when passed an array value containing two strings when trying to generate a link

Tags: php

I have an array $option['option_name'] where each option_name is a string such as Biology, Computer Science, Chemistry, etc.

```
$option = array('Biology', 'Computer Science', 'Chemistry');
```

I am looping through this array and generating links to images like this:

```
<img src = <?php echo '.. /../../ExamGuy/public/img/catalog/'. $option['option_name']. '.png' ;? > alt="" class="img-circle">
```

It prints the links for single string array values like Biology and Chemistry well and the images show, but for double string array values like Computer Science it prints just the first string (Computer) and equally leaves out the .png part.

So i have ExamGuy/public/img/catalog/Biology.png

But for Computer Science it prints just ExamGuy/public/img/catalog/Computer

Comment: So, in your array, you're not specifying the image extensions? Are all images of extensions png? Also, please specify the image names for each one of these.

Comment: Yes all images are png, equally I've given them names as in the array above such as Biology.png, Computer Science.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of your echo part. Just put it in a loop of yours. I attached a compiled code to show that it is echoing the correct path and file name.

```
echo ".. /../../ExamGuy/public/img/catalog/". $option[0].".png";
echo ".. /../../ExamGuy/public/img/catalog/". $option[1].".png";
echo ".. /../../ExamGuy/public/img/catalog/". $option[2].".png";
```

https://repl.it/DobN/4

Comment: Ok thanks. But as I've edited $option doesn't have [option_name] by it. Was a mistaken assignment by the stack app. Pls try with just $option = array(...)

Comment: Answer updated. I also updated the link and it still shows the complete path and file name. :) @LeonelElimpe

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't mentioned the correct array indices. Try this:

```
<?php foreach ($option as $opt) { ?>
   <img src = <?php echo '.. /../../ExamGuy/public/img/catalog/'. $opt['option_name']. '.png' ;? > alt="" class="img-circle">     
<?php } ?>
```